# How I run the replace function one time?

Tags: javascript, onchange

I want the `replaceFunction` to run only one time. For now works correctly only on first time, `E-1` return `Ε-1 (APPLE)` but when user try to edit text field again system detect
**Ε-1** and return `Ε-1 (APPLE) (APPLE)`..

```
td.onchange = function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/(\E-(\d+))/g, replaceFunction);

    function replaceFunction(match) {
        // add additional rules here for more cases
        if (match === "E-1") return "Ε-1 (APPLE)";
        if (match === "E-2") return "Ε-2 (SUMSUNG)";
        .
        .
        .
        if(match === "E-99") return "Ε-99 (LG)";
        return match;
    }
}
```

How I stop this?

Comment: Consider using an object whose keys are the matches to find, whose values are the replacements - then, use a replacer function to look up the appropriate value on the object, It'll be a lot less repetitive than 100 `if`/`else`s

Comment: can you post a working snippet?

Comment: A clarification question: if the user types "an E-1" would you like it to change it to "an E-1 (APPLE)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this one more condition:

```
if (match === "E-1" && match !== "Ε-1 (APPLE)") return "Ε-1 (APPLE)";
```

this can be optimized, if you put the mapping into object:

```
var map = {
    "E-1": "Ε-1 (APPLE)",
    ...
}

if (map[match] && !map[match] !== match) { return map[match]; }
```

and for this to work you will need regex that also match the word after in bracket:

```
var names = ['APPLE', 'SAMSUNG'];

var re = new RegExp('(E-(\\d+))(?! \\((?:' + names.join('|') + ')\\))', 'g');
```

Yet another solution is to use only array (this will only work if you E-NUM match index in array)

```
var names = ['APPLE', 'SAMSUNG'];
var re = new RegExp('(E-(\\d+))(?! \\((?:' + names.join('|') + ')\\))', 'g');
// regex explanation, same as yours but \\d is because it's a string
// we create negative look ahead so we check if next text
// after E-1 is not " (" and any of the names.
// we use (?: to group what's inside it's the same as with ()
// but the value will not be captured so there will be
// no param in function for this group
// so this regex will be the same as yours but will not match "E-1 (APPLE)"
// only "E-1"

this.value = this.value.replace(re, replaceFunction);

function replaceFunction(match, eg, num) {
   // convert string to number E starts 
   var i = parseInt(num, 10) - 1;
   if (i <= names.length) {
     return match + ' (' + names[i] + ')';
   }
}
```

the regex and function can be created outside of the change function, so it don't create new function on each change.

Comment: I'm not particularly good at Regex so this may be way off, but wouldn't `match` always be just an "E-(digit)"?

Comment: My point is, if the `match` is the "E-1", then `match !== "Ε-1 (APPLE)"` will be true no matter what follows the match in the full string.

Comment: This is true (same thing I was suggesting in my comment), but does not answer the question

Comment: @DBS yes, I know figure it out (was confused after I've read you comment first time), that's why I've deleted the comment and agree with you, I've updated my answer with better regex.

Answer (score 1):

When replacing, also optionally lookahead for a space and parentheses that come after. This way, in the replacer function, you can check to see if what follows is *already* the value you want (eg, `(APPLE)`). If it is, then do nothing - otherwise, replace with the new string:

```js
const replacementsE = [
  , // nothing for E-0
  'APPLE',
  'SUMSUNG',
];

td.onchange = function(e) {
  td.value = td.value.replace(/E-(\d+)(?= \(([^)]+)\)|)/g, replaceFunction);

  function replaceFunction(match, digits, followingString) {
    const replacement = replacementsE[digits];
    if (!replacement || replacement === followingString) {
      return match;
    }
    return `E-${digits} (${replacement})`;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="td">
```

What `/E-(\d+)(?= \(([^)]+)\)|)/` does is:

- `E-` - Match `E-`
- `(\d+)` - Capture digits in a group
- `(?= \(([^)]+)\)|)` Lookahead for either:

  - `\(([^)]+)\)` A literal `(`, followed by non-`)` characters, followed by `)`. If this is matched, the non-`)` characters will be the second capture group
  - `|` - OR match the empty string (so that the lookahead works)

The digits will be the first capture group; the `digits` variable in the callback. The non-`)` characters will be the second capture group; the `followingString` variable in the callback.

If you also want to permit the final `)` to be deleted, then make the final `)` optional, and also make sure the character set does not match spaces (so that the space following `APPLE`, with no end `)`, doesn't get matched):

```js
const replacementsE = [
  , // nothing for E-0
  'APPLE',
  'SUMSUNG',
];

td.onchange = function(e) {
  td.value = td.value.replace(/E-(\d+)(?= \(([^) ]+)\)?|)/g, replaceFunction);

  function replaceFunction(match, digits, followingString) {
    const replacement = replacementsE[digits];
    if (!replacement || replacement === followingString) {
      return match;
    }
    console.log(followingString)
    return `E-${digits} (${replacement})`;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="td">
```

If you want to permit *any* number of characters before the final `)` to be deleted, then check if the replacement `startsWith` the following string:

```js
const replacementsE = [
  , // nothing for E-0
  'APPLE',
  'SUMSUNG',
];

td.onchange = function(e) {
  td.value = td.value.replace(/E-(\d+)(?= \(([^) ]+)\)?|)/g, replaceFunction);

  function replaceFunction(match, digits, followingString, possibleTrailingParentheses) {
    const replacement = replacementsE[digits];
    if (!replacement || replacement === followingString || replacement.startsWith(followingString)) {
      return match;
    }
    
    return `E-${digits} (${replacement})`;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="td">
```

Comment: friend add E-1 and system return E-1 (APPLE) if user delete for mistake a ")" and system value is E-1 (APPLE system return again E-1 (APPLE) (APPLE ... :( I think we need a other regex to check for words APPLE or SAMSUNG ...

Comment: See edit, make the final `)` optional, and change the character set

Comment: Again we have bug there, write E-1 and then delete "E)" system return E-1 (APPLE) (APPL and if delete characters  return again E-1 (APPLE) (AP,E-1 (APPLE) (

Comment: It's impossible to account for all possible mis-types the user makes. I suppose you could check to see if the text to possibly replace `startsWith` the captured text, but this is starting to sound like a bit of a [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-question).

Comment: See edit, but like I said, there are many possible typos one could make, and it's not possible to programatically listen for all of them

Comment: I test now the @jcubic solution and system not return bug if I delete characters... but thank you for the answer friend